# Is applying a gaussian kernel a fancy way of saying convolving with a gaussian mask?

Tags: terminology

When someone says apply gaussian kernel, is that the same thing as saying, convolve it with a gaussian mask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Convolution in spatial domain, or dot product in frequency domain.

Comment: that's becuz the cool thing is that the Fourier Transform of a gaussian is a gaussian.  it's one of the few functions that have that as an **inherent** property.  you can always construct a million different functions that have self-similar Fourier Transform, but the gaussian and the dirac comb are the two that come to mind where you **don't** need to contrive the function.